# Click event is not working in grid view in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have one templete field inside grid view, code is written as below :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="40px" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="javascript:fillBankDetails(<%# CreateBankDetailsArray(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")) %>);window.close();" >Select</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and javascript function is written as below

```
function fillBankDetails(bankDetails) {
    alert('Hello');
    isSelected = true;
    var a = JSON.parse(bankDetails);
    window.returnValue = a[0];
}
```

When I click on select, click event is not firing. Did I have done any mistake. Please help in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked generated html, also errors in console if any?

Comment: check your HTML, if this line of code is giving output as desired:
<a href="javascript:fillBankDetails(<%# CreateBankDetailsArray(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")) %>);window.close();" >Select</a>

Comment: Post the browsers html code ... if it contains " (double quotes) it messes things up

Comment: The above gride view is used for dailog box. so i cann't put break point in browser and one more thing is that the java script function is written in .aspx page, so there also i cannt put debbuger. These are the problem i am facing in debugging.

Comment: Post the browser html page code after loading please. What's important is how the result of the `CreateBankDetailsArray(Eval("DataItem"))` method looks like

Comment: Please find below the HTML code:

    <a href="javascript:fillBankDetails([{"Address1":"ROAD 14-D,     SECTOR-4","Address2":"UTTARA MODEL TOWN","Address3":"HOUSE 11","City":"DHAKA","IbanNumber":"","ProvinceState":"","AccountNumber":"","CountryCode":"BD","IsFoundInDb":"true"}]);window.close();" >Select</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<a href="javascript:fillBankDetails(<%# CreateBankDetailsArray(Eval("DataItem")) %>);window.close();" >Select</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code but with this code click event is working properly but data is not displaying correctly in  dialog box

Comment: what do you mean by not displaying correctly? what is wrong?